# How to optimize query across all domain controllers to find the latest logon date?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, hashtable

I'm currently trying to query the domain controllers to find the latest logon date for users. I know I can use the lastlogondate but that doesn't get replicated as often as I'd like and I have no control over the that. I tried making a script to query each domain controller and check it against a hashtable of users but this is proving to be really slow to even query one DC. I know I could run background jobs for each DC but still just going all the latest logon times for one domain controller is taking a long time. Any advice?

```
$dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter {Name -like "*"}
$users = Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=users,DC=com"
$outfile = "c:users.csv"
$usertable = @{}

# creating table for all users
foreach($user in $users) {
    $userobject = New-Object PSObject
    $userobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DomainController -Value "0"
    $userobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LastLogon -Value "0"

    $usertable.Add($user.SamAccountName ,$userObject)
}    # end foreach

# Method for looping through domain controllers to find last logon

foreach($dc in $dcs) {
    $hostname = $dc.HostName

    $logons = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=users,DC=com" -Property LastLogon -Server $hostname

    foreach($u in $logons) {
        $sam = $u.SamAccountName

        if($u.LastLogon -gt $usertable.$sam.LastLogon) {
            $usertable.$sam.LastLogon = $u.LastLogon
            $usertable.$sam.DomainController = $dc.HostName
            Write-Host "$sam has the latest date"
            $usertable.$sam.DomainController
        }
    }    #end inner foreach
}        #end outer domain foreach

foreach($h in $usertable.GetEnumerator()) {
    $sam = $($h.Name)
    $newdate = $($h.Value).LastLogon

    $append = "$sam,$newdate"
    $append | out-file $outfile -Encoding ascii -Force -Append
}
```

Comment: Do you need to collect for disabled accounts?

Comment: How many domain controllers and users do you have?  I have a similar program generating an excel report across ~2500 users & 18 DCs, and it takes about 10 minutes to run. What's the current performance look like given the #DCs & users?

Comment: @Steven 12 domain controllers with ~15k users.  Even with like 10 minutes of running it only got through about 100 users for the first DC.

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen No I don't but the disabled accounts make a very small portion anyways.

Comment: @fruit Are you perhaps running this from your laptop/workstation over a VPN connection? You'll likely improve query response time by executing on a server with more direct routes to the DCs

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm going to speak on behalf of @ fruit here.  I don't think that's it. I tested in my environment which is direct and could reproduce his slowness.  Check my answer for more info.  Would love to hear what you think.

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen I am running this from my workstation but not over VPN, the system didn't have any slowness getting a list of all logons from each DC but rather doing the comparison.  Steven solved the issue and thinks the objects could still have a connection to the DC which is why the comparison is taking a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured this out.  It's very clear from testing and comparing with my own similar program that the delay is in the following loop:

```
foreach($u in $logons) {
    $sam = $u.SamAccountName

    if($u.LastLogon -gt $usertable.$sam.LastLogon) {
        $usertable.$sam.LastLogon = $u.LastLogon
        $usertable.$sam.DomainController = $dc.HostName
        Write-Host "$sam has the latest date"
        $usertable.$sam.DomainController
    }
} # end inner foreach
```

Now my program is not exactly the same as yours. One could sanitize this, but for all intents and purposes the below segment serves the same function as the above excerpt:

```
# Note: the re-use of $DC...
ForEach($DC in $RDCs )
{   # Should you add any measurements here??
    Write-Host "Working on $DC : $(Get-Date -Format G) ..."
    Get-ADUser -Filter $Filter -SearchBase $SearchBase -Server $DC -Properties $AD_Props |
    ForEach-Object{
        If ( $Users.Contains( $_.samAccountName ) )
        {   # So you don't attemp when it wasn't in the root set.
            If( $_.lastlogon -gt $Users[$_.samAccountName].LastLogon )
            {
                $Users[$_.samAccountName].LastLogon = $_.lastlogon
                $Users[$_.samAccountName].DC = $DC
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that I'm using a `ForEach-Object` loop instead of the `ForEach` construct.  However, this isn't a sufficient explanation, especially seeing as the latter is often faster.

Note: I timed your loop in several different ways and accounted for code earlier in the script.  For example, I'm not creating the objects the same way, but I ruled that out as a factor.

Not able to figure out why your loop would be "dramatically" slower I relucantly rewrote it to:

```
$logons |
ForEach-Object{
    If( $_.LastLogon -gt $usertable[$_.samAccountName].LastLogon )
    {
        $usertable[$_.samAccountName].LastLogon = $_.LastLogon
        $usertable[$_.samAccountName].DomainController = $hostname
```

However, this didn't seem much faster if at all. So, even more reluctantly I tried it like:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $UsersOU -Property LastLogon -Server $hostname |    
ForEach-Object{
    If( $_.LastLogon -gt $usertable[$_.samAccountName].LastLogon )
    {
        $usertable[$_.samAccountName].LastLogon = $_.LastLogon
        $usertable[$_.samAccountName].DomainController = $hostname

    }
}
```

Now I started seeing performance similar to my own program. In fact, it seemed a little faster, probably due to not checking the Hash.

Based on experience I can only hypothesize that the objects are live and maintaining some kind of connection back to the source DC.  I've seen this type of thing once before in the PowerShell Community Extensions (PSCX) the objects returned from `Get-TerminalSession` exibited similar behavior.  I could be crazy,  I'm happy to be corrected and frankly hoping someone has a better explanation.

There are a few other things I can advise here, none as impactful as above. Please also note, I didn't test through to the end, and so can't guarantee there aren't other issues.

Comment: Thank you!  Yeah your rewrite is much faster and your hypothesis on it still having a live connection or some sort of requery makes sense.  I was at first thinking maybe it also has something to do with the object creation as well but I wouldn't think it would dramatically affect it so the live connection to the DC does make a lot of sense.  Thanks again!